# How do I create an instance of value from the attribute's meta object with Moose?

Tags: perl, serialization, moose, metaclass

I'm working on a serialization tool using Moose to read and write a file that conforms to a nonstandard format.  Right now, I determine how to load the next item based on the default values for the objects in the class, but that has its own drawbacks.  Instead, I'd like to be able to use information in the attribute meta-class to generate a new value of the right type.  I suspect that there's a way to determine what the 'isa' restriction is and derive a generator from it, but I saw no particular methods in Moose::Meta::Attribute or Class::MOP::Attribute that could help me.

Here's a bit further of an example.  Let's say I have the following class:

```
package Example;
use Moose;

use My::Trait::Order;
use My::Class;

with 'My::Role::Load', 'My::Role::Save';

has 'foo' => (
    traits => [ 'Order' ],
    isa => 'Num',
    is => 'rw',
    default => 0,
    order => 1,
);

has 'bar' => (
    traits => [ 'Order' ],
    isa => 'ArrayRef[Str]',
    is => 'rw',
    default => sub { [ map { "" } 1..8 ] }
    order => 2,
);

has 'baz' => (
    traits => [ 'Order' ],
    isa => 'Custom::Class',
    is => 'rw',
    default => sub { Custom::Class->new() },
    order => 3,
);

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
1;
```

(Further explanation: `My::Role::Load` and `My::Role::Save` implement the serialization roles for this file type.  They iterate over the attributes of the class they're attached to, and look at the attribute classes for an order to serialize in.)

In the `My::Role::Load` role, I can iterate over the meta object for the class, looking at all the attributes available to me, and picking only those that have my Order trait:

```
package My::Role::Load;
use Moose;    

...

sub load {
    my ($self, $path) = @_;

    foreach my $attribute ( $self->meta->get_all_attributes ) {
        if (does_role($attribute, 'My::Trait::Order') ) {
            $self->load_attribute($attribute) # do the loading
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I need to know the `isa` of the attribute that the meta-attribute represents.  Right now, I test that by getting an instance of it, and testing it with something that's kind of like this:

```
use 5.010_001; # need smartmatch fix.
...
sub load_attribute {
    my ($self, $attribute, $fh) = @_;
    my $value = $attribute->get_value($self); # <-- ERROR PRONE PROBLEM HERE!
    if (ref($value) && ! blessed($value)) { # get the arrayref types.
        given (ref($value)) {
            when('ARRAY') { 
                $self->load_array($attribute);
            }
            when('HASH') {
                $self->load_hash($attribute);
            }
            default {
                confess "unable to serialize ref of type '$_'";
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        when (\&blessed) {
            confess "don't know how to load it if it doesn't 'load'."
                if ! $_->can('load');
            $_->load();
        }
        default {
            $attribute->set_value($self, <$fh>);
        }
    }
}
```

But, as you can see at `# <-- ERROR PRONE PROBLEM HERE!`, this whole process relies on there being a value in the attribute to begin with!  If the value is undef, I have no indication as to *what* to load.  I'd like to replace the `$attribute->get_value($self)` with a way to get information about the type of value that needs to be loaded instead.  My problem is that the docs I linked to above for the `Class::MOP::Attribute` and the `Moose::Meta::Attribute` don't seem to have any way of getting at the type of object that the attribute is supposed to get.

The type information for an attribute is basically what I'm trying to get at.

(Note to future readers: the answer here got me started, but is not the final solution in of itself.  You will have to dig into the `Moose::Meta::TypeConstraint` classes to actually do what I'm looking for here.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure I follow what you are after and perhaps Coercions might do what you want?

However to get the attributes *isa*:

```
{
    package Foo;
    use Moose;

    has 'bar' => ( isa => 'Str', is => 'rw' );
}


my $foo = Foo->new;

say $foo->meta->get_attribute('bar')->type_constraint;   # => 'Str'
```

/I3az/

Comment: Type_constraint - aha!  I think that's it!

Comment: Ok, thanks for getting me on the right track.  Time to ask a better formatted version of the question. :)

Comment: Glad to be of assistance.   I only knew of $attribute->type_constraint from when I read this excellent blog post by Sartak: http://blog.sartak.org/2009/06/mooses-mop-schematize.html

Answer (score 2):

Out of curiosity why not use/extend [MooseX::Storage](http://search.cpan.org/dist/MooseX-Storage)? It does Serialization, and has for about two and a half years. At the very least MooseX::Storage will help you by showing how a (well tested and production ready) serialization engine for Moose is written.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure I understand (perhaps you can include some pseudocode that demonstrates what you are looking for), but it sounds like you could possibly get the behaviour you want by defining a new attribute trait: set up your attribute so that a bunch of methods on the class delegate to the attribute's object (`isa => 'MySerializer', handles => [ qw(methods) ]`).

You might possibly also need to subclass [Moose::Meta::Class](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Moose::Meta::Class) (or better, add a role to it) which augments the behaviour of `add_attribute()`.

Edit: If you look at the source for [Moose::Meta::Attribute](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Moose::Meta::Attribute) (specifically the `_process_options` method), you will see that the `isa` option is processed by [Moose::Util::TypeConstraints](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Moose::Util::TypeConstraints) to return the actual type to be stored in the `type_constraint` field in the object.  This will be a [Moose::Meta::TypeConstraint::Class](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Moose::Meta::TypeConstraint::Class) object, which you can make calls like `is_a_type_of()` against.

This field is available via the `type_constraint` method in Moose::Meta::Attribute. See [Moose::Meta::TypeConstraint](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Moose::Meta::TypeConstraint) for all the interfaces available to you for checking an attributes's type.